# Metric invariance: CFI difference test and Chi square difference test. What happens when contradictory results are found?

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, invariance

I have been examining a sample (n > 600) for metric invariance, using AMOS. Using the Comparative Fit Index (CFI) difference test, which seems to be free of sample size influence, I get evidence of metric invariance (Cheung & Rensvold, 2002; suggested to use this). However, if I use chi square difference test, I dont get such evidence, and even whe I go into details looking for invariance in specific factors I dont find it. Byrne (2013) says it is basically a matter of like to chose either chi square difference test or CFI difference test. **How could I interpret these contradictory results?**
Moreover, as well as I understand, one reason for not using chi square is because as a sample increases it is very likely to always get significance (and therefore, to conclude there is invariance when it might be false). But in this case, chi square tells me there is no invariance. Thanks in advance!

References

Cheung, G. W., & Rensvold, R. B. (2002). Evaluating goodness-of-fit indexes for testing measurement invariance. Structural Equation Modeling, 9(2), 233-255. doi: 10.1207/S15328007sem0902_5

Byrne, B. M. (2013). Structural equation modeling with AMOS: Basic concepts, applications, and programming. New York: Routledge

Comment: what's a "CFI difference test"?

Comment: It's a test to compare two nested models, basically is a substraction of, let's say, the CFI of model 1 from the CFI of model 2. Check the references I gave (Cheung & Rensvold, 2002; Byrne, 2013). Used to examine invariance.

Comment: You should (i) give complete references in your post, and (ii) not assume people know what CFI is (i.e. expand abbreviations, except the most common across statisticians from different application areas)

Comment: Thank you for asking. CFI is the Compartive Fit Index.                              Bentler, P. M. (1990). Comparative fit indexes in structural models. Psychological Bulletin, 107(2), 238-46                                                                                              The other references I provided are:                                            Cheung, G. W., & Rensvold, R. B. (2002). Evaluating goodness-of-fit indexes for testing measurement invariance. Structural Equation Modeling, 9(2), 233-255. doi: 10.1207/S15328007sem0902_5

Comment: Comments have a word limit, Glen_b. So I add the last full reference in another comment: Byrne, B. M. (2013). Structural equation modeling with AMOS: Basic concepts, applications, and programming. New York: Routledge.

Comment: The intent of the phrase "in your post" was that you make the changes to the question, not that you put them in comments. Please edit your question; people should be able to find the relevant information there.